# Consider a function $f:\{{1,2,3,\cdots,13}\} \rightarrow \{{1,2,3,\cdots,9}\}$ Given that function is surjective and non–decreasing

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinations

> > Consider a function $f:\{{1,2,3,\cdots,13}\}$$\rightarrow$ $\{{1,2,3,\cdots,9}\}$ Given that function is surjective and non–decreasing, the probability that $f(7)=4$ is?

**My solution:**
Let $x_k$ denotes number of times $k$ appears in range. where $1\leq k \leq 9$

Then number of non decreasing and onto function $f:\{{1,2,3,\cdots,13}\}$$\rightarrow$ $\{{1,2,,3,\cdots,9}\}$ is equal to number of positive integral solution of equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_9=13$ i.e., ${13-1\choose 9-1}= {12 \choose 8}$.

**Total Function: ${12\choose4}$**

Number of function satisfying above property is i.e., $f(7)=4$

is number of positive integral solution of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=7$ and $x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8+x_9=6$ that is ${6 \choose 3}\times{6\choose 5}$.

**Note:$x_4 \geq 0$ in $x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8+x_9=6$ and rest all $x_i \geq 1$**

I've obtained the correct result i.e., $\frac{{6\choose 3}\cdot {6\choose1}}{{12\choose 4}}$as given in answer key.

I've edited the solution as commented by @mathlover.

Also is there any other approach for this problem.

Comment: You are actually looking for solution to $x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7+x_8+x_9 = 6, x_4 \geq 0, x_5..x_9 \geq 1$

Comment: @MathLover Oops, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_i$ is minimal $x$ such that $f(x)=i$. Then $a_1=1$, $a_{i+1}>a_i$, $a_9\leq 13$. There is $\binom{12}{8}$ ways to choose $a_2$, ..., $a_9$, so there are $\binom{12}{8}$ functions $f$. We believe that all these functions are equally probable, otherwise we need additional information to solve the problem.

If $f$ is such that $f(7)=4$ then $a_4\leq 7$ and $a_5 \geq 8$. Then there are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$ and there are $\binom{6}{5}$ ways to choose $a_5$, ... , $a_9$. Total numbers of functions $f$ satisfying $f(7)=4$ is $\binom{6}{3}\cdot \binom{6}{5}$.

The probability is $\frac{\binom{6}{3}\cdot \binom{6}{5}}{\binom{12}{8}}$.